# How to access history in a component that is not in Router List?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I know there are a few questions about it but I can't get it working.
When I use useHistory() in searchbar component, i got undefined in history.
The same when I tried to access history.push via props, because Searchbar is not listed in Routes.jsx. How can I progamatically navigate to other route from a component that is no in routes list?

That is my app.js

```js
function App () {
  return (
    <ItemsProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <Header logo={Logo} />
        <main className="container">
          <Routes />
        </main>
      </div>
    </ItemsProvider>
  );
}
```

Routes.jsx

```js
export default props => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/items/:id" component={Item} />
        <Route path="/items" component={Results} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Searchbar.jsx

```js
export default props => {
  let history = useHistory();

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.push(`/items?q=${document.getElementById('searchBar').value}`);
  };

  return (
    <form className="search col-9" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="searchBar"
        placeholder="Nunca deixe de buscar"
        className="search-bar"
      />
      <button className="search-bar--submit">
        <img src={SearchIcon} alt="Search Icon" />
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is the Searchbar component inside the Header component? If so, move your BrowserRouter up a few levels so that Searchbar is a descendant of it.

Comment: Yeah! Searchbar is in Header component, header also is not in Route list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useHistory() will use the react context api to look for the BrowserRouter (or other router). So the BrowserRouter needs to be somewhere farther up the component tree, and right now it's not. My recommendation would be to remove Browser Router from Routes.jsx and put it into App.jsx.

```
// App.jsx
function App () {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ItemsProvider>
        <div className="App">
          <Header logo={Logo} />
          <main className="container">
            <Routes />
          </main>
        </div>
      </ItemsProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

// Routes.jsx
export default props => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/items/:id" component={Item} />
      <Route path="/items" component={Results} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```